# JavaScript array map return multiple value

Tags: javascript

Now I have array like this:

```js
let arr = [{
    name: 'Tony', age: 17, love: [1, 2, 4]
}, {
    name: 'David', age: 12, love: [6, 6, 6]
}, {
    name: 'John', age: 10, love: [0, 0, 0]
}]
```

And I want to map this array and get result

```
const a1 = arr.map(man => {
    if(man.name === 'Tony') {
        for(let i = 0; i < man.love.length; i++) {
            return man.love[i]
        }
    }
    else {
        return man.name
    }
})
```

The result I want is `[ 1, 2, 4, 'David', 'John' ]`.

But I got `[ 1, 'David', 'John' ]`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: A map will return exactly as many outputs as you have inputs. You want a *reduce* or a plain old loop.

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 4):

What you need is [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). It allows you to return arrays which will then be flattened.

```js
let arr = [{
    name: 'Tony', age: 17, love: [1, 2, 4]
}, {
    name: 'David', age: 12, love: [6, 6, 6]
}, {
    name: 'John', age: 10, love: [0, 0, 0]
}]

const a1 = arr.flatMap(man => {
    if(man.name === 'Tony') {
        return man.love
    }
    else {
        return man.name
    }
})

console.log(a1);
```

Answer (score -1):

it is rather necessary to make the loop with man.love.length

```
const a1 = arr.map(man => {
    if(man.name === 'Tony') {
        for(let i = 0; i < man.love.length; i++) {
            return man.love
        }
    }
    else {
        return man.name
    }
})
```

Comment: 1) Useless loop, 2) still not the desired result.